# Cannot Create OAuth Consumer

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, api, rest-api, oauth

I am trying to set up OAuth access to an API for a site running 1.9.3.2. All of the Magento instructions say:

> You can register your application by selecting **System > Web Services > REST - OAuth Consumers** and clicking **Add New** in the Admin Panel.

[Source](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html)

The problem with this is that the dashboard I am looking at does not have any "REST - OAuth*" options in the System menu.

[image]

I haven't been able to find any configuration anywhere to enable this or any plugin that may be conflicting and I am at a loss as to why these options are here when everything seems to indicate they should just always be in that menu.

Is there something that needs to be enabled somewhere that I am unaware of? Or something that could conflict and cause these menu items to not appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out my issue. In **System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Advanced**, I had to enable **Mage OAuth**. Then I had to go to **System -> Cache Management** and run **Flush Magento Cache**. I was unaware that settings and modules for the actual admin dashboard would also be cached and not automatically flushed when settings are updated.